# Inline alignment of tikz graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf

## How it should look like

I want to achieve the following result using `TikZ`. The graphic should be aligned to the right of the text body and to the top of the line's text it is placed in.

Besides, the graphic should "overlay" the following lines.

[image: Desired result]

## What I tried so far and how it looks

The graphic itself should be placed inside a command and is more complex than the one inside this MWE. I played around a lot with `baseline`, `overlay`, `xshift`, `yshift` and a lot more, but couldn't get it work ... Neither the alignment, nor the "overlay".

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \goodluck { } {
  \hfill
  \tikz[baseline=1.75cm, overlay]{%
    % Do some more complex TikZ stuff
    \fill[blue] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
    \fill[red] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2);
  }
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli

Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla \goodluck

Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub 

\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the KOMA option `parskip=half` there must be at least `1em` free space
in the last line of a paragraph. So with \hfill there is a distance of `1em` to the right border of the text body.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \goodluck { } {
  \hfill
  \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{%
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east](n)at(-1em,0){\strut};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% -> overlays its contents
      % Do some more complex TikZ stuff
      \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1);
      \fill[blue] (0,-1) rectangle (-1,-2);
      \draw(-4,0)--(4,0)(0,-4)--(0,4);% to show the alignment and the origin of the picture
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  }
}

\begin{document}

Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli Bli

Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla \goodluck

Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub Blub 

\end{document}
```

[image]